# Replace a word in an address string with dictionary value using for-loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have an address `2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PL` which I expect to get `2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PLACE` as a result after spelling out the PL to PLACE. I have a dictionary of abbreviated street names:

```
st_abbr = {'DR': 'DRIVE',
            'RD': 'ROAD', 
            'BLVD':'BOULEVARD',
            'ST':'STREET', 
            'STE':'SUITE',
            'APTS':'APARTMENTS', 
            'APT':'APARTMENT',
            'CT':'COURT',
            'LN' : 'LANE',
            'AVE':'AVENUE',
            'CIR':'CIRCLE',
            'PKWY': 'PARKWAY',
            'HWY': 'HIGHWAY',
            'SQ':'SQUARE',
            'BR':'BRIDGE',
            'LK':'LAKE',
            'MT':'MOUNT',
            'MTN':'MOUNTAIN',
            'PL':'PLACE',
            'RTE':'ROUTE',
            'TR':'TRAIL'}
```

with a for-loop, I would like to replace the key in address be spelled out. What I thought I should do is loop through each word in the address, thus I have the address.split(), and if the split match one of the keys in the dictionary, to replace that with a spelled out word.

```
for key in st_abbr.keys():
        if key in address.split():
            address = address.replace(key, st_abbr[key])
        print(address)
```

It works perfectly on abbreviated street names but this is what I get `2300 S SUPER TEMPLACEE PLACE`. It also replaced the PL within 'TEMPLE' with PLACE, thus it gave me 'TEMPLACEE'. I am trying to modify the for loop to only replace the abbreviated street if the street.split() is the exact match of the dict.keys(). I would like guidance on how to achieve that.

Comment: Why not 1) identify which element(s) of `address.split()` `key` is in, 2) replace those elements, then 3) `join` those elements to get the string with the replacements?

Comment: You're looking up each key to see if it's in the address. I'd flip it around and look up each part of the split address to see if it's one of the keys of the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottHunter, I tried the following `for text in address.split():` `if text in st_abbr.keys():` `address = address.replace(text, st_abbr[text])` I get the same results. Maybe there is something wrong with my replace line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comprehension:

```
addr = '2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PL'
new_addr = ' '.join(st_abbr.get(c, c) for c in addr.split())
print(new_addr)

# Output
2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PLACE
```

> Can you shed a light the concept behind the .get(c,c) in the context of my problem?

```
# Equivalent code
' '.join(st_abbr[c] if c in st_abbr else c for c in addr.split())
```

Comment: The idea behind the code above is exactly what @ScottHunder described. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: which line above should I put this?

Comment: It replaces your whole code.

Comment: Hi, that makes sense, but I get he same results, maybe I have it wrong in the replace line? `for text in address.split():`  `if text in st_abbr.keys():` `address = address.replace(text, st_abbr[text])`

Comment: Your code works fine for me but it is not efficient. What's wrong with my solution? Is it not working as expected?

Comment: I have not tried yet.

Comment: It worked! Can you shed a light the concept behind the .get(c,c) in the context of my problem? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with an equivalent code. Is it clear for you?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it's the best idea or not, but regex usually can be helpful in these cases:

```py
import re

def getValue(value):
  before = value.group(1)
  name = value.group("name")
  after = value.group(3)
  if name in st_abbr:
    return before + st_abbr[name] + after
  else:
    return before + name + after

myString = "2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PL"
re.sub("(^|\s)+(?P<name>[A-Z]{2,4})($|\s)", getValue,myString)
```

##### Output

```
2300 S SUPER TEMPLE PLACE
```

Comment: thanks. I got a typeError, expected a string or bytes-like object. I am trying to apply this to a df with an address column with few observations and eventually use it to my actual df having 10million observations.